# How can we handle catched error returned from 3 nested stored procedures on Snowflake into the main procedure's catch block

Tags: javascript, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a Snowflake JavaScript main procedure SP1, which is looping over N staged files, whereas another stored procedure SP2 is called.

Within SP2, a third procedure SP3 is called to get the data into a temporary table.

```
SP1() {
  try{
    for (stg_file in array_of_files) {
      // set some metadata and time variables
      call SP2();
      insert log into log table;
      return result;
    }
  } catch(error) {
    insert error into log table;
    return error;
  }
}

SP2() {
  try{
    call SP3();
    return result to SP1;
  } catch(error) {
    return error to SP1;
  }
}
```

When I run SP2() by itself, I can get a detailed error the way I organized in its catch part:

> {
>
> Error: "EXISTS",
>
> ErrorMsg: "Unknown field",
>
> ErrorCode: 123,
>
> StagedFile: 'Data.csv'
>
> }

However the error returned from SP1(), is more generic and does not reflect the detailed error returned by SP2():

> Error in script: can't find field_table.

One of the changes I made is to remove all try-catch from SP2 and SP3, and I've placed SP1 try-catch inside the loop, but the it's only going over 1 file instead of N.

Answer (score 1):

If SP2 errors then what is being returned to SP1 is just the string you've chosen to return, not an error object. Therefore SP1 is not going to throw an error if SP2 errors.

In SP1 you would need to check the contents of the string returned from SP2 and take an action depending on the contents e.g. throw an error that includes the string returned from SP2

Comment: True. It worked. The error thrown was nothing but an array returned to the variable calling the child procedure.